# Region is missing error - AWS Amplify React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to upload a file to AWS using amplify with React js but I'm getting a  `07:55.748 AWSS3Provider - error uploading Error: Region is missing`.

This is the code that I'm using. I even trying hard coding the region but it still isn't working.

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { createDrawing as CreateDrawing } from '../graphql/mutations';
import { listDrawings as ListDrawings } from '../graphql/queries';
import config from '../aws-exports';
const { aws_user_files_s3_bucket: bucket } = config;

export const listDrawings = async () => {
    const images = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(ListDrawings));

    console.log(images.data.listDrawings.items);
    return images;
};

export const createDrawing = async (file) => {
    const region = 'eu-west-1';
    const extension = file.name.split('.')[1];
    const imgName = file.name.split('.')[0];
    if (file) {
        const { type: mimeType } = file;
        const key = `images/${uuid()}${imgName}.${extension}`;
        const url = `https://${bucket}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/public/${key}`;
        const inputData = { name: imgName, image: url };

        try {
            await Storage.put(key, file, {
                contentType: mimeType
            });
            await API.graphql(
                graphqlOperation(CreateDrawing, { input: inputData })
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error: ', err);
        }
    }
};
```

I also tried updating `aws-amplify` but it didn't solve my problem once again.

Comment: set the environment variable `AWS_REGION=eu-west-1` before starting your service

Comment: Sorry for asking, but where do I set that variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In repository from where you are exporting your files, there is a file with name  **aws-exports.js**

It should have a structure like:

```
/* eslint-disable */
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "region",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_cognito_region": "region",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "oauth": {xxxxxxxx}
};


export default awsmobile;
```

In the region, edit the region you want to add like eu-west-1.

You can also try to manually add configuration in the file like this instead of importing from **aws-exports.js**:

```
import Amplify, { Auth, Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
Auth: {
    identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', //REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    region: 'XX-XXXX-X', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
},
Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
        bucket: '', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket name
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I already did that, but somehow the error still occurs

Comment: @Guilhermeffable Can you also confirm that you are using the latest aws-amplify version, right ? Please mention the aws-amplify version too.

Comment: I'm using version 6.13.4

Comment: @Guilhermeffable Check with manual configuration too, see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I did that. ```Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'eu-west-XXXXXXXX',
        region: 'eu-west-1', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        userPoolId: 'eu-west-1_sGAh3YygY', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolWebClientId: '6gu5avich36l4icvngtb3e57ph'
    },
    Storage: {
        AWSS3: {
            bucket: 'XXXXXXXX', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket
            region: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region
        }
    }
});```

I still get the error, maybe i'm using it wrong

Comment: @Guilhermeffable Please refer to this documentation, it might help you. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js#manual-setup-import-storage-bucket

Comment: I followed that guide and it worked! Now I'm getting an `(TypeError): Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined`, if you can't help me I'm really grateful for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Guilhermeffable  "If you can't help me" Sorry but Is it a typo in your above comment ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I was asking if you could help with the TypeError. But I just figured that I'm gonna start from scratch and follow the tutorial from aws documentation you sent me yesterday. You were a great help.

Comment: @Guilhermeffable No problem, glad to help you, if you are building from scratch I would also recommend you to go through this guide, it is helpful: https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-from-react-app-using-aws-amplify-b286dbad2dd7

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I followed everything in the link you sent me and I'm getting a `No credentials error`, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Guilhermeffable Can you please open another question for this error along with all the details of the error and error code, so that we do not merge 2 questions in 1.
And also,
If the above answer solved your previous problem you can mark it as answer otherwise no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Above solution didnt work for me. So I tried this in index.js:

```
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "./aws-exports";
Storage.configure({
    region: config.aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region,
    bucket: config.aws_user_files_s3_bucket,
    identityPoolId: config.aws_user_pools_id,
    level: "protected",
});
```